# Comment traduire « anti-pattern » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais

[Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antipattern) propose d'utiliser l'anglicisme *antipattern* ou bien anti-patron. Le TLF définit bien "pattern", mais pas "anti-pattern". Je trouve que "anti-patron" seul sonne lutte des classes. Je pencherais vers "anti-patron de conception". Est-ce que quelqu'un connaît une autre traduction ?

Comment: un contre-modèle ?

Comment: On évitera *anti-patron*, pourtant de circonstance en cette période trouble.

Comment: @jlliagre Ça me paraît très bien comme traduction, à mon avis ça mérite d'être posté comme réponse.

Comment: @BenC pourquoi le traduire ? Dans quel cadre ?

Comment: cf commentaire plus bas : Mon besoin était pour de la vulgarisation ou de la présentation à des non-informaticiens. Sinon je conserve un jargon technique anglais lors d'échanges entre informaticiens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Anti-pattern* est connu et utilisé dans le milieu informatique mais pour avoir une traduction bien française, je suggérerais :

> un contre-modèle.

Le *pattern* correspond au modèle qu'il faut suivre ou dont il faut s'inspirer, le contre-modèle marquant alors l'inversion, l'opposition au modèle.

On peut cependant peut-être percevoir une nuance car s'il semble qu'*anti-pattern* a toujours une connotation négative en anglais en tant que représentation de ce qu'il ne faut pas faire, un contre-modèle n'est pas toujours ressenti comme erroné mais peut être au contraire un choix défendable et judicieux.

Note à propos de patron. En raison de la portée limitée du sens de « patron » pour « modèle », surtout limité à la couture, comparée à l'omniprésence du sens habituel de « chef d'entreprise », anti-patron n'a guère de chance de s'imposer et est même plutôt indéfendable ici.

Il est d'ailleurs amusant d'observer qu'un même mot latin, *Patronus*, a pu évoluer vers des sens aussi divers en français comme en anglais. Des places de parking indiquant *patrons only* sont très déconcertantes...

Comment: On peut écrire la même chose au sujet de motif que de patron. C'est en fait un peu plus vicieux encore car la traduction usuelle de pattern est *motif* lorsqu'il s'agit du sous-domaine informatique du traitement d'image, mais *modèle* quand il s'agit d'ingénierie de système

Comment: @qoba La traduction de pattern par motif est pertinente (un pattern/motif qui se répète). Il n'y a pas d'anti-pattern dans ce cas.

Comment: Oui motif garde le sens de répétition mais perd le sens d'inspiration recommandable, important dans *design patterns*

Answer (score 2):

*Archétypes d'erreurs (de conception)* est peut-être plus vaste, car il ne garantit pas qu'il s'agisse de prime abord d'une technique courante apparemment utile (donc possiblement un *piège à éviter*...) mais qui s'avère de *deuxième ordre* vu qu'une meilleure solution existe (les [critères](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern#Definition) permettant de la distinguer de la simple *mauvaise habitude/idée/pratique*, selon l'article Wikipedia de langue anglaise). Une *fausse bonne solution* à certains égards. L'[*archétype*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/arch%C3%A9type/5034?q=arch%C3%A9type#5008) c'est le *modèle* ou le *type*, mais on trouve plus clair (vu qu'on n'est pas du tout versé dans le domaine) de l'utiliser pour regrouper les erreurs plutôt que a contrario ou par « extrusion » avec l'élément [*anti-*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/anti-) pour *contre la notion* (la notion étant celles des pratiques validées dans le domaine, des grands principes etc.), quoiqu'on trouve la solution avec [*contre*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/29896) fort excellente maintenant qu'on sait de quels modèles il s'agit. Mais on pense que de dire qu'il s'agit exactement de principes ou techniques qui s'érigent contre les/s'opposent diamétralement aux *meilleures pratiques* et les (aux) *règles de l'art*, voire aux *principes fondamentaux* en conception, des « anti-principes » pour ainsi dire... serait exagéré il me semble, vu l'idée de piège et celle de catégories d'exemples. Ce pourrait être de *grands pièges* en conception (les fameux *pitfalls*), des *exemples/prototypes classiques* d'erreurs, de *vecteurs de contre-productivité, d'anomalies*, en conception etc. À sa plus simple expression des *erreurs courantes* (Wikipédia).

Comment: "Fausse bonne idée" est le terme que j'emploierais personnellement. Bon matériel dans la réponse mais présentation assez confuse...

Answer (score 1):

Je crois que l'on peut simplement utiliser anti-pattern. Pourquoi cherche-t-on toujours à traduire en français ou à franciser des mots issus de l'informatique ? Les personnes auxquelles vous vous adressez peuvent les comprendre.

http://jargonf.org/wiki/anti-pattern

https://blog.xebia.fr/2015/03/04/cinq-anti-patterns-devops/

**EDIT**

Je ne voulais violer aucune loi :-) !

Mon dictionnaire (livio) affirme que pattern est un anglicisme informatique (ellipse). Il donne comme signification patron de conception.

Il donne également le contraire antipattern venant de l'anglais anti-pattern/antipattern. Il donne comme signification patron de conception considéré comme une erreur.
Il donne comme synonyme antipatron.

Il cite le livre "Performance des architectures IT - 2e éd.: Comprendre, résoudre et anticiper" dans lequel anti-pattern apparaît.

https://books.google.fr/books?id=Otdp6xQfznUC&pg=PA59&dq=comprendre+r%C3%A9soudre+et+anticiper+pascal+antipattern&hl=el&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiz3ZqB89PaAhWMEywKHflwCrwQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=comprendre%20r%C3%A9soudre%20et%20anticiper%20pascal%20antipattern&f=false

Vu que antipattern signifie en anglais : A design pattern that may be commonly used, but is ineffective or counterproductive in practice (software engineering) et que pattern peut se traduire en français comme modèle l'on peut employer contre-modèle (comme @jlliagre a déjà proposé).

Cependant, moi je prefère toujours anti-pattern ou bien antipattern (en allemand il existe aussi Anti-Pattern):-)!

Comment: *Pourquoi cherche-t-on toujours à traduire en français ou à franciser des mots issus de l'informatique ?* C'est une question sensible. On peut le faire tout bêtement pour respecter la loi (loi Toubon en France, loi 101 au Québec).

Comment: @dimitris je vous rejoins sur le fait de conserver un jargon technique anglais lors d'échanges entre informaticiens. Mon besoin était pour de la vulgarisation ou de la présentation à des non-informaticiens. Merci pour vos échanges.

Comment: @BenC Maintenant je comprends.